# How to resize linux partition with RAID1?

Tags: partition, raid1, fdisk

I have a Proxmox disk with 130Gb LVM image. I moved it to 235Gb disk. And resized in the Proxmox. Done.

But in my Linux distro, the partition still 130Gb (disk become 235Gb).

The partitions:

- `/dev/sda1`
- `/dev/sdb1`

They are part of RAID1 volume: `/dev/md0`

What is the correct way to resize it from 130Gb to 235Gb without loosing data?

```
root@debian:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 235 GiB, 252329328640 bytes, 492830720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd098f1da

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 273436671 273434624 130.4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       273436672 291502079  18065408   8.6G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 235 GiB, 252329328640 bytes, 492830720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x559572cb

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 273436671 273434624 130.4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       273436672 291502079  18065408   8.6G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 130.3 GiB, 139864309760 bytes, 273172480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md1: 8.6 GiB, 9241100288 bytes, 18049024 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

---

```
root@debian:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      9024512 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      136586240 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/2 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

---

```
root@debian:~# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8       16  246415360 sdb
   8       17  136717312 sdb1
   8       18    9032704 sdb2
   8        0  246415360 sda
   8        1  136717312 sda1
   8        2    9032704 sda2
  11        0    1048575 sr0
   9        0  136586240 md0
   9        1    9024512 md1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Same [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492672/56572) was asked and answered on Unix & Linux StackExchange site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it was crossposted.